# Postman. How can I use assertion / expect and console log together?

Tags: api, postman, chai

```
pm.test('Check if employee filled their skills', function() {
    jsonData.forEach(function(item) {
        expect(item.MainEmployeeSkills).to.be.not.empty;
        if (item.MainEmployeeSkills.length < 1) {
            console.log(item.fullName + " doesn't have skills");
        }
    })
})
```

After expect code is unreachable. But I want to know that test failed and log results.
Please, help

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonData = [2, 2, 3, 2, 2]

jsonData.forEach(function (a) {
    pm.test("Your test name", function () {
        if (item.MainEmployeeSkills.length < 1) {
            console.log(item.fullName + " doesn't have skills");
        }
        pm.expect(a).to.eql(2);

    });

})
```

you should print it before the pm.expect as it throws an exception and nexyt line won't be executed.

Also there is no point of  having for loop inside pm.text as the loop exists for the first except itself ( unless this is what you want )

If you are looking way to print descriptive assertion message yu don't havr to do this. Instead use:

```
pm.test('Check if employee filled their skills', function() {
    jsonData.forEach(function(item) {
        pm.expect(item.MainEmployeeSkills,item.fullName + " doesn't have skills").to.be.not.empty;

    })
})
```

[image]